# How to align dropdown to right of mat-card-title element?

Tags: html, css, angular

**Goal**: Align Dropdown to right side of other element

**Problem**: It always displays below

This is an Angular site

**What I've tried**:
I've tried adding the mat-select within a mat-form-field and assigning a css class.
I've also tried placing a form around that and then palcing the mat-card title within the form.
I've also tried changing the width of the mat-card-title
I've tried placing a div around both of these elements

**HTML**:

```
<mat-card class="login-card">
    <div>
        <mat-card-title class="text-center" i18n="@@MoVeSeLo_H1_1">
            Please Sign In
        </mat-card-title>
        <form [formGroup]="_siteForm">            
            <mat-form-field class="right">
                <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" placeholder="Language">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                        {{language.viewValue}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
       </form>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

**CSS**:

```
.login-card {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 80rem; }

.mat-form-field {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 30rem; }

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Picture showing where it currently is, and arrow pointing to where I'd like it to be:
[image: Sign in page]

Comment: Can you add JS code or provide jsfiddle link?
Then it would be easier to provide the solution

Comment: Could you please describe in more details how the card look like? It's hard to figure it out from the question description. Do you want the input with dropdown to be placed inside the title to right of the text?

Comment: @ValeriyKatkov I just added an image. Does this help?

Comment: @SarveshMahajan I had included html and css as this is a UI/alignment issue. Are you suggesting this to be affected by the Typescript? I included an image to help clarify.

Comment: @angleUr Please find below my answer, you can achieve this using CSS position property

Answer (score 1):

You can put the select and the title into a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), like:

```html
<mat-card class="login-card">
  <form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
    <div class="title-container">
      <mat-card-title i18n="@@MoVeSeLo_H1_1">
        Please Sign In
      </mat-card-title>
        <mat-form-field class="language-field">
            <mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" placeholder="Language">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language">
                    {{language.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

```css
...

.title-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.language-field {
  margin-top: -16px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

I've also adjusted margins of the select input in order to make it looking correctly.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxryui-gja7kf?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.css)

---

But if you want the title to be centered inside the card, it's easier to use 'absolute' position for the select, instead of using the flexbox, like:

```css
...

.title-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.language-field {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -16px;
}
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxryui-2dgndn?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.css)

Comment: Thanks @Valeriy . This does align the dropdown to the right of the title, but it pushed the title to the left of the screen. Sorry if I did not clarify that. I wanted to keep the title centered as it is, but have the dropdown to the right. I'm trying to play around with margins to try to achieve this.

Comment: @angleUr In this case, it's easier to use `absolute` position instead of flexbox. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Valeriy, I updated with this. Its in the correct position now, although I put width: 200px back on .language-field because the dropdown was overlapping onto the title.

Answer (score 0):

The simple and easiest way, this can be managed using position CSS

```css
  #parent { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 500px; 
  height: 400px; 
  background-color: #fafafa; 
  border: solid 3px #9e70ba; 
  font-size: 24px; 
  text-align: center; 
} 
#child { 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: #fafafa; 
  border: solid 3px #78e382; 
  font-size: 24px; 
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
 <div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'></div>
</div>
```

property, please find below code snippet: